# Jira Custom Order By on Updated date/time

Tags: jira, jql

I have got the below ORDER BY JQL script added to my boards. For some reason though the issues are not re-ordering. Is there something that I am missing?

```
ORDER BY updatedDate desc
```

Comment: What it shows if you use your JQL in search? Is it showing the same result or it shows different result? It might be indexing issue as well :-)

Comment: It shows the exact same result like nothing has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA boards can be set to sort by "Rank", which will override and remove any other ranking; see [Enabling Ranking](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/enabling-ranking) and [Ranking an Issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/working-with-issues/ranking-an-issue). If that's not set, ORDER BY works for me in JIRA Cloud.

Comment: I tried to follow those links you referenced but I am unable to find the Board > Configure option on my JIRA cloud. Do you happen to know where this configuration option has moved to?

Comment: It's now under "Board Settings" in the "..." menu at the top right. It took me a while to find it (and other things) again when they changed the interface to hide more things in that "..." menu.

Comment: Thanks for the redirect, that was indeed where it was moved to. I found it after clicking the '...' > Board Settings > Edit Filter Query. From there I can edit the filter query directly. Thanks for all your help with this Mike